# What is the output of the convolutional layer if the filter is the same image itself with which the convolution is being carried out?

Tags: image-processing, convolution

Lets say, image A has to be convolved with a filter and the filter is image A only with the exact same dimensions. What should be the output of this convolution? Will it be the image itself? Blurred or intensified?

Comment: Could you explain more about the convolution you have in mind? what do you mean by "the filter is image A"? If there is only one image and there is no room to move the convolutional window for 'valid' convolution, then the result is just a number! If the convolution is done with padding over all possible locations, the result is more like a blurry black and white image A fading in borders and corners.

Comment: As far as I understand the question, there are no neural networks, yet convolutional (err... correlational), here. Please remove those tags.